# Optimizing trigonometric and nonlinear functions

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

First, Please, keep in mind that I'm a programmer not mathematician, and I have a fair mathematical background.

I used optimization in Java to fit some observations to a trigonometric function, I tried the following optimizers: BOBYQA, CMA-ES, Powell, and Simplex to optimize the function as a scalar function, and also Levenberg-Marquardt and Gauss-Newton to optimize it as a vector function, I got good results for

> $z = a.\sin(x)+b.\cos(y)$

, but for a non-linear relation like: $y = \cos(a.x)$ or $z = \sin(a.x) + \cos(b.x)$, the results are very unsatisfying and I have to choose an initial guess very close to the correct values of $a$ and $b$, and certainly this is not practical, example:

> $y=6.4\cdot e^{5.5x}$

gives

> $(6.39 \text{ and } 5.5)$ if the initial guess is set to
>   $(7,7)$

and gives

> $(2.07 \text{ and }5.5)$ for initial guess of $(8,8)$

and , certainly, this is a very bad guess.
So I guess I need either of two choices:

1. Find a method for selecting a very good initial guess
2. Find a method for improving the optimizer so that it could get a good result even if the initial guess is not good.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make I understand the question ... you used various optimization techniques to find values of $a$ and $b$ that make the function $y = ae^{bx}$ best fit some observed $(x,y)$ data values. And you ran into the trouble you described. Is that correct?

Comment: I see that BOBYQA was written by M. J. D. Powell. He is one of the world's leading experts on optimization, so I assume that his software is of high quality. I've done similar optimizations myself (though not using any of the packages you mentioned), and my experiences have been much better than yours. Most algorithms have trouble if the objective function is very badly behaved, or the starting point is far from the desired solution, but I don't think either of those two problems are present in your example. I would expect better results, even with a less-than-ideal starting point.

Comment: bubba, Yes, exactly.
I also was expecting better results, because (8,8) is not very far from the correct guess, please notice that the above result are obtained by a Levenberg-Marquardt Optimizer, this is exactly what I did:
- Generated 35 of random values
- Calculated y = 3.4 * e^(2*x) for every point
- Implemented a function that calculates z = a*e^(b*x) to be used by the optimizer
- Set the initial guess to (8,8)
- Set the bounds to (16,16)
- Set the number of interpolation points of BOBYQA Optimizer to 4 (Is is suitable?)
- Specified 1000000 maximum iterations

how to estimate init guess?

Comment: Right. (8,8) is not very far from the right answer, and I'd expect any decent optimization function to perform properly. I can only guess at what the problem might be. I'd suggest you use a larger number of interpolation points ($m$). A quadratic function of two variables has 6 degrees of freedom, so using $m= 4$ points seems too small, to me. Powell suggests using $m = 2n+1 = 5$. Another idea: use Mathematica or something similar to graph the objective function, and see if there's anything strange about it.

Comment: Thanks, I printed out the calculated values and compared them with the original observations, this gave me an idea about how the algorithm develops results, I could finally figure out the reason, it is **falling in a local optimum** I'll write the solution below
Thanks

Comment: Aha. So, if the objective function has local minima, then, as far as I know, the only possible approach is to start your iterations at several different locations, and hope that one of these iterations leads to a global minimum. Not very scientific. To find good starting ponts, you can just sample the objective function and try to find places where it's small. Since your solution space is only 2D, that's not too bad.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and multi-start optimization does that

Comment: I know you've answered your own question now, but I'm still curious to understand what optimization problem you're solving.  What is the function that you're minimizing?

Comment: @littleO - I want to implement a method (function) in Java to fit some observations to any multivariate function, this method receives the observations along with the multivariate function (e.g. a.cos(b.x)+c.sin(d.y)) and finds the constants (a,b,c, and d), this _model_ can be used later to predict the value of some phenomenon based on some measurements (observations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it, the problem was caused by falling in a local optimum, following is a short comparison between results I got from the mentioned algorithms:

- [Powell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powell%27s_method) and [BOBYQA](http://openopt.org/BOBYQA) give wonderful results with [**high precision** but **low accuracy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision), this means that you have to provide a **very good initial guess** and **rather tight bounds**
- [Simplex](http://www.chem.uoa.gr/applets/AppletSimplex/Appl_Simplex2.html) is slightly better in **not falling in a local optimum**, I think this is because it uses **[Nelder-Mead Simplex](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%25E2%2580%2593Mead_method&ei=OkoTUpfQFM-V7AbN-4CIBQ&usg=AFQjCNEVD7lMV4buMbVCJ3fuiyupPA6B1w&sig2=xXTpyqps1xi5SuHBeTUNKw&bvm=bv.50952593,d.ZGU)** or **[Multi-Directional Simplex](http://scholarship.rice.edu/handle/1911/16304)** to update its guesses, both allows providing **long steps** to search far from the initial guess and thus **avoiding the local optimum**, it also requires **no bounds**, it estimates them well
- [CMA-ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMA-ES) is much more accurate but slightly less precise, it allows you to specify **bounds** and **step length**, but strangely gives different results for different runs and some of them may fall in a local optimum.

I finally made the following algorithm to get reliable, accurate, and precise results:

1. Use CMA-ES to get a rough estimation with high accuracy
2. Calculate the mean squared error
3. If the mean squared error is larger than a threshold, repeat CMA-ES again
4. With acceptable error, use Simplex to get a more precise result
5. I also used a [Multi-Start-Multivariate optimizer](http://www.solver.com/content/basic-solver-multistart-methods-global-optimization) with CMA-ES and simplex to help avoiding local optima

This gave acceptable results